# Vector space closed under scalar multiplication, what is the domain of c?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, terminology

I was introduced to vector spaces recently, and when considering that they must be closed under multiplication.

$$c\mathbf{U} \in \boldsymbol{H} \text{ given } \mathbf{U} \in \boldsymbol{H}$$

What is the domain of $c$? Is it any element of any vector in $\boldsymbol{H}$?

---

We have primarily been talking about vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so it has been handwaved as "any real number". But if it was an element, does that imply that you could define a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}^n$, $\mathbb{Z}^n$, or $\mathbb{N}^n$?

How does that relate to polynomial spaces or the vector space of all real-valued functions?

Comment: $c$ is a scalar in the scalar field.  Multiplication of a vector by a scalar from the designated scalar field is among the things that need to be defined for a vector space to make sense.  Often times the most elementary vector spaces you are introduced to will have scalar field $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, but there is no requirement that it be one of these.  It could be any field, finite or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector space is a triplet $(V,F, \psi)$ where $V$ is a commutative (Abelian) group and $F$ is a field and $\psi$ is a  special kind of function from $F\times V$ to $V.$

Before going further, a few standard conventions:

$+$ is used for the group-operation of $V$ and also for the addition-operation of $F.$

$ 0$ is used for the group-identity of $V$ and also for the additive-identity of $F.$

$1$ is used for the multiplicative-identity of $F.$

$fv$ is used for $\psi(f,v).$

The special properties of $\psi$ are:

If $f_1,f_2\in F$ and $v\in V$ then $(f_1+f_2)v=(f_1v)+(f_2v)$ and $f_1(f_2v)=(f_1f_2)v.$

If $f\in F$ and $v_1,v_2\in V$ then $f(v_1+v_2)=(fv_1)+(fv_2).$

If $f\in F$ and $v\in V$ then $[\,fv=0$ iff ($f=0$ or $v=0)\,].$

If $v\in V$ then $1v=v.$

This is called a vector-space over $F.$ But it is very common to refer to $V$ as the vector-space.

In some contexts $vf$ is defined to be $fv$ when $f\in F$ and $v\in V.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer I don't think I could have understood it without JMoravitz's comment. To check my understanding $F$ is the same as the scalar field JMoravitz was talking about? When I am learning about vector spaces in linear algebra $\psi$ is scaler matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes. $F$ is also called the field of scalars or the scalars.  Members of $V$ are called vectors. My choice of the symbol $\psi$ was arbitrary.